# apache virtualhost with condition

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have added an Apache proxy for node application, below is my conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName main.open.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/maint-test
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 404 /test.html
    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyPass /test.html !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4130/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4130/
</VirtualHost>
```

The above configuration works fine but I want to add a condition that if `test.html` is present in `DocumentRoot` then it should show `test.html`, else it should use `ProxyPass`.

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: Your configuration seems correct `ProxyPass /test.html !` should not proxy /test.html, what happend when you try yourserver/test.html ? What is wrote in access or error logs. I think you are trying to redirect localhost:4130 404 errors to /test.html, but you are doing it in Apache instead of your localhost:4130 application. You application on port 4130 should trigger /test.html to works as you want (even if /test.html doesn't exist on localhost:4130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Rewrite Rules with Proxy support instead. I have tested this & it works.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName main.open.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/maint-test
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 404 /test.html
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !test.html
       RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:4130/$1 [P,L]

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} test.html
       RewriteCond /var/www/vhosts/maint-test%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^/test.html$ http://localhost:4130/test.html [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```